# Two way socket communication: socket is closed

Tags: android, sockets

I am trying to sending and receiving data between two mobile phones. Right now I can send data from one device (device 1) to another (device 2), however, when I am reading data in the same device (device 1) I am getting following error:

```
java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed
```

I am using the following code to read data:

```
SocketServerReadThread socketServerReadThread = new SocketServerReadThread(socket);
 socketServerReadThread.run();

 private class SocketServerReadThread extends Thread {

      private Socket mySocket;

      SocketServerReadThread(Socket socket) {
          mySocket = socket;
      }

      @Override
      public void run() {


        try {
            inputStream = mySocket.getInputStream();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(1024);
            int bytesRead;

            while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1){
                   byteArrayOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                   response += byteArrayOutputStream.toString("UTF-8");
               }

            MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                 @Override
                 public void run() {
                     msgRead.setText(" Response: "+response);
                 }
                });


        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block

            e1.printStackTrace();
            message += "Read Something wrong! " + e1.toString() + "\n";
        }
      }
}
```

I would appreciate if anyone could help me to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
 private class SocketServerReadThread extends Thread {
 private Socket mySocket;

  SocketServerReadThread(Socket socket) {
      this.mySocket = socket;
  }

  BufferedReader input;
  input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    this.mySocket.getInputStream()));


  @Override
  public void run() {
 while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {

            try {

                String read = input.readLine();
                System.out.printf("Message read is -> %s%n", read);
                if (read != null) {

msgRead.setText(" Response: "+response);   
}
}catch(Exception e){}}}}
```

Comment: Hi Raj, Thanks for your reply. I have changed my code according to your suggestion. However, I am getting the same error.

Comment: here are the erros:
java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.checkNotClosed(PlainSocketImpl.java:134)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.getInputStream(PlainSocketImpl.java:216)
at java.net.Socket.getInputStream(Socket.java:344)
at com.example.mytestserver.MainActivity$SocketServerReadThread.run(MainActivity.java:218)
at com.example.mytestserver.MainActivity$SocketServerThread.run(MainActivity.java:193)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)

Comment: change the code to other side also because u cant read byteArrayInputStream with  BufferedReader

Comment: sorry, I didn't get you. on other side I am just sending data... not reading any data